# convert ktx to png with alpha channel

Tags: opengl-es, png, pvrtc

I extracted KTX textures from an Android game and I tried to convert them using PVRTexToolCLI, however the PNGs do not contain any alpha channel information. Also, some KTX images are not 2 powered size and PVRTexToolCLI does not support them. Is there any solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Are you certain they do contain alpha?

FWIW, using PVRTexToolGUI, I just created a PVRTC 4bpp texture that contained varying alpha in ktx format and then decompressed it using:

PVRTexToolCLI.exe -i *SrcFileName.ktx* -f r8g8b8a8 -d *OutputFileName.png*

which worked as expected. I can't comment onthe size question though.

To be honest, you *might* be better off asking this sort of question on the [PowerVR Insider Graphics](https://community.imgtec.com/forums/cat/powervr-insider-graphics/) Forum

Comment: Thank you for your answer I have work out that problem. I found that they stored alpha channel in ktx file bytesOfKeyValueData part https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/KTX/file_format_spec so I convert it to png  Using PVRTexToolCLI and write a script to retrieve alpha channel from ktx

Comment: Very helpful!  Also, for DuckDuckGo visitors, I found PVRTexToolCLI binaries for various platforms in the `bin` folder as part of this open source project: https://github.com/TimvanScherpenzeel/texture-compressor

Comment: @DWoldrich FWIW binaries should be freely available from the powervr dev site https://www.imgtec.com/developers/powervr-sdk-tools/powervr-sdk/ (link towards the bottom of the page)